# Explicitly type a destructured function parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I currently have:

```
const Start = ({ onSubmit }) => {
```

But this is the start for a definition of a React component defined in a TypeScript environment. I get a red squiggly warning that onSubmit is of implicit any type. I would like it to be fully typed. So I defined it as:

```
const Start = ({ onSubmit: (event: BaseSyntheticEvent<object, any, any> | undefined) => Promise }) => {
```

Now I get a warning that there is an eslint parse error indicating that ';' was expected. How do I type a destructured function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a type to assign `Start`, such as:

```js
type StartFunction = (args: {
  onSubmit: (
    event: BaseSyntheticEvent<object, any, any> | undefined
  ) => Promise<void>;
}) => void;

const Start: StartFunction = ({ onSubmit }) => {
  // ...
};
```

With that said, if you're creating a functional component in React you can simply leverage their already existing `FC` type which includes a generic for specifying props, which you can then destructure:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';

type StartProps = {
  onSubmit: (
    event: BaseSyntheticEvent<object, any, any> | undefined
  ) => Promise<void>;
};

const Start: FC<StartProps> = ({ onSubmit }) => {
  return <></>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the type for the object that is passed as argument, for example

```js
const Start = ({
  onSubmit,
}: {
  onSubmit: (
    event: BaseSyntheticEvent<object, any, any> | undefined
  ) => Promise<void>;
}) => { /* component logic */ };
```

Since this will for a React component, I suggest using the `FC` generic provided by React and explicitly create an interface for props outside of the function signature.

```js
interface IStartProps {
  onSubmit: (
    event: BaseSyntheticEvent<object, any, any> | undefined
  ) => Promise<void>;

  // any other props that need to passed to the Start component
}

const Start: React.FC<IStartProps> = ({ onSubmit }) => { /* component logic */ }
```